# Session handling in django

Tags: python, django, session-cookies

I have created web-app in django. App doesn't require any login logout activity. But, I used session variable and I am not deleting session. will it harm my site database?

Comment: what do you mean by "harm"?

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question.

Comment: If it is in session, there's nothing to do in your database. Only if you start messing with payments (but nobody would make payment without login). In some cases, session can give some errors and send multiples forms/payments. So, it have to be designed proper. BUT, I dont think it would harm your db.

Answer (score 0):

// setting session in login view

```
........
 def LogIn(request):
  if user.check_password(entered_password):
        print('found')
        request.session['user_session_id'] = user.id
```

// checking sessions on index

```
def Onboarding(request):
# context = {'foo': 'bar'}
if 'user_session_id' not in request.session:
    print('no session found')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login_signup.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'feed/feed.html')
```

// deleting session on logout

```
def logout_user(request):
try:
    print('session deleted')
    del request.session['user_session_id']
except KeyError:
    pass
return render(request, 'accounts/login_signup.html')  # redirecting to login page
```